# Xcode: How to turn off the compiler error messages in the source code window?

Tags: xcode, macos

The source code editor in XCode 3.1 has a new feature where your compiler error (and warning) messages are embedded directly in your code below the relevant line of text.  I'm sure it sounded like a nice idea, but in practice I find it very annoying - your code jumps around as you try to make the edits to fix the error.

I know you can collapse the error message by clicking the marker icon in the left margin, but I'd prefer not to have them appear directly in my code at all.  Is there any way to disable this feature?  Surfing the preferences pane didn't turn up anything.

Memo to Apple: Tool tips would be a much better solution.

Comment: Note that in Xcode 3.2 the message bubbles are not embedded in the text (they fill available white space), so your text does not jump around any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences -> Building -> Message Bubbles -> Show during builds: Never

---

Xcode 7+

Preferences -> Behaviors -> Build -> Succeeds/Fails -> Notify using bezel or system notification

Answer (score 5):

> Go to Xcode preferences and uncheck "Show live issues" from the General tab.

Source: [Is there some way to stop XCode from showing errors and prompts while I type the code?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-some-way-to-stop-XCode-from-showing-errors-and-prompts-while-I-type-the-code/answer/Anthony-Frenet)

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 14: Menu > Xcode >Settings >
General > Issues: Show Minimized