# Pragma to turn off Xcode error "Redundant conformance of 'CGPoint' to protocol 'Hashtable'"

Tags: xcode, swift2

I have some Swift code to extend `CGPoint`:

```swift
extension CGPoint: Hashable {
    public var hashValue:Int {
        return self.x.hashValue ^ self.y.hashValue
    }
}
```

The very first line produces an error in Xcode, Redundant conformance of 'CGPoint' to protocol 'Hashable':

[image: Xcode screenshot showing error message]

But it is not redundant. The following line of code, later in my Swift file, relies on it:

```swift
private var borderPoints:Set<CGPoint>?
```

As it stands the code builds and runs fine, i.e. I can ignore the Xcode error message. If I take heed of the error message and remove the protocol  conformance (which Xcode believes is redundant) my code fails to build and Xcode gives the error Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable':

[image: Xcode screenshot showing second error]

Since my code now does not build this is an error I have to fix, i.e. I have to include the protocol conformance that Xcode complained of earlier.

Swift is a new language so I don't mind too much if this is just a bug in Xcode's understanding of extensions and protocol conformance but I would like to turn off the error message. [I know how to turn them off for the entire project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447033/575530) but what is the Swift code pragma to turn this error message off for just this line?

Comment: Quick answer for this, `CGPoint` use `Equatable` protocol, and `Hashable` use `Equatable` protocol, then you can not use `Hashable` protocol onto the `CGPoint` .

Comment: So how do we make CGPoint hashable so that CGPoints can be included in Sets?

Comment: I use ```override var hashValue: Int {
        get { return something }}``` and ```override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool { return true or false}``` . these are used in objective-c style. But I don't know that is fit to CGPoint.

Comment: Have you found the answer for this?